# Making list of model into field of another model in django

Tags: django, list, django-models

I am totally newbie in django and I am trying to make a restaurant app. I have two models: component and meal, and i want to make a field in meal model that contains a list of components models. Is there any way to do such a thing ? For example sandwich contains bread, cheese and ham.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case, you should use [ManyToMany](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/). Your models should be like this:

```
class Component(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    # other fields

class Mean(models.Model):
    components = models.ManyToManyField(Component)
```

usage:

```
meal = Mean.objects.create(name = "Sandwich")
bread = Componrnt.objects.create(name='Bread')
mean.components.add(bread)
```